Replacing strings with special characters in R
I have a dataset with German special charaters (ä, ö, ü, ß) and other special characters (brackets (), /, \, etc.):
df <- data.frame(
id = 1:8,
date = seq.Date(as.Date("2024-12-01"), as.Date("2024-12-08"), "day"),
group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 4),
text1 = c("Österreichische Botschaft", "Außenministerium", "Bundesheer", "Präsident",
          "Bundesregierung / Bundeskanzler", "Parteien", "Justiz", 
          "Erwerbstätig (unselbständig)")
)

I have another dataset containing the original strings and the replacement strings:
df_replace <- data.frame(
original = c("Österreichische Botschaft", "Außenministerium", "Präsident",
             "Bundesregierung / Bundeskanzler", "Parteien", "Justiz", 
             "Erwerbstätig (unselbständig)"),
replacement = c("Austrian embassy", "Foreign ministry", "President",
                "Government / Chancellor", "Parties", "Judiciary", "Working (employed)")
)

I now want to replace all the strings in df using the df_replace dataset.
Using stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed works fine, as long as the number of rows in the df and the df_replace datasets are the same:
df |> mutate_all(\(x) stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(x, df_replace$original,
                                           df_replace$replacement))

But this is not the case for my df.
Hence, I receive the following error-message:
Caused by warning in "stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed()": ! longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
In addition, this solution only works, if the terms are in the same order. For example, if I switch the first terms ("Österreichische Botschaft", "Austrian embassy") to the last position, there are no replacements anymore.
Using the following code did not work either:
df |> mutate_all(\(x) stringr::str_replace_all(x, df_replace$original,
                                                  df_replace$replacement))

Because with stringr::str_replace_all I run into problems because of the special characters (especially the brackets).
Is there another way how to solve this problem?

An approach using match
transform(df, repl = df_replace$replacement[match(text1, df_replace$original)])

output
  id       date group                           text1                    repl
1  1 2024-12-01     A       Österreichische Botschaft        Austrian embassy
2  2 2024-12-02     B                Außenministerium        Foreign ministry
3  3 2024-12-03     A                      Bundesheer                    <NA>
4  4 2024-12-04     B                       Präsident               President
5  5 2024-12-05     A Bundesregierung / Bundeskanzler Government / Chancellor
6  6 2024-12-06     B                        Parteien                 Parties
7  7 2024-12-07     A                          Justiz               Judiciary
8  8 2024-12-08     B    Erwerbstätig (unselbständig)      Working (employed)


this works fine for one column, but not for multiple columns. Furthermore, if there is no match, the original value should remain. In addition, there should not be a new variable, but the original column should remain and the values in the column should be changed according to the replacement file. Hence I used the mutate_all function.

You may simply do a left join:
dplyr::left_join(df, df_replace, by=c("text1" = "original"))


this works fine for one column, but not for multiple columns. Furthermore, if there is no match, the original value should remain. In addition, there should not be a new variable, but the original column should remain and the values in the column should be changed according to the replacement file. Hence I used the mutate_allfunction.
